# Act on errors in NPM commands run from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, npm

I have an NPM command that I am running from PowerShell:

```
npm install process-migrator -g 
process-migrator
```

This command returns an error when its not configured properly, but I cant seam to pick it up in PowerShell.

```
[ERROR] [2018-09-25T15:30:30.610Z] Cannot find configuration file 'configuration.json'
[INFORMATION] [2018-09-25T15:30:30.615Z] Generated configuration file as 'configuration.json', please fill in required information and retry.
```

**Is there some way to get the error?**

I have tried:

```
if($?) {            
   Write-Host "Process-Migrator completed sucessfully." $LASTEXITCODE           
} else {   
   Write-VstsTaskError "Process-Migrator FAILED " $LASTEXITCODE -ErrCode $LASTEXITCODE
} 
Process-Migrator completed sucessfully. 1
```

But $? is returning true and $LASTEXITCODE is a 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to capture the output of the application *first*:

```
$output = & 'process-migrator.exe' 2>&1
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    $err = $output.Where{$PSItem -match 'ERROR'}
    Write-VstsTaskError "Process-Migrator FAILED: $err" -ErrCode $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

*Note: I made an assumption about the extension to be more granular with the execution*

Comment: Can you explain what the first `&` sign means after the `$output =`?

Comment: For future visitors: I added the following line within the `if` statement to pass the exit code to the poweshell exit like that: `exit $LASTEXITCODE;`

Comment: @BrunoBieri [Special operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#special-operators)